# Why do I keep getting an exception about "an element with the same key already exists" in this code?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to follow this tutorial about [object pooling in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdSmKaJvCoA)

I got to minute 17:22. But when I run the game I get this exception:

```
ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary.

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[UnityEngine.GameObject]].Add (System.String key, System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1 value) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:404)
ObjectPooler.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/ObjectPooler.cs:31)
```

This script is attached to a new empty GameObject:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Pool
    {
        public string tag;
        public GameObject prefab;
        public int size;
    }

    public List<Pool> pools;
    public Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>> poolDictionary;

    private void Start()
    {
        poolDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>>();

        foreach(Pool pool in pools)
        {
            Queue<GameObject> objectPool = new Queue<GameObject>();

            for (int i = 0; i < pool.size; i++)
            {
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(pool.prefab);
                obj.SetActive(false);
                objectPool.Enqueue(obj);

                poolDictionary.Add(pool.tag, objectPool);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Like in the tutorial I'm making size of 1 of the Pools in the Inspector then giving as tag name: Cube then drag a cube prefab to the Prefab then set the size to 150.

But I'm getting this exception when running the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the innermost loop of `Start()`, you're trying to add `objectPool` to the `poolDictionary` using `pool.tag` as the key. This innermost loop executes once for every slot in the pool, and `pool.tag` is the same for each invocation, thus the exception. It also doesn't seem to make that much sense, placed there.

It looks to me like what you *want* is to add `objectPool` to `poolDictionary` outside the `for` loop, and add each new game object to `objectPool` inside the `for` loop. Something like this:

```
foreach(Pool pool in pools) {
  Queue<GameObject> objectPool = new Queue<GameObject>();

  // Insert into poolDictionary here, not in the loop below.
  poolDictionary.Add(pool.tag, objectPool);

  for (int i = 0; i < pool.size; i++) {
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(pool.prefab);
    obj.SetActive(false);
    objectPool.Enqueue(obj);
  }
}
```

Provided every `pool` has a unique `tag` value, this should work the way you expect.